# Can we add a extra claims in Azure AD Groups when we create them via Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to add extra properties to the Azure AD groups when we create them in azure ad b2c via graph api. Just like we do it for users (we can add claims to the user)

I am not able to find any resource for this. let me know if that is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer to help other people who have similar question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could do that.

Find the "b2c-extensions-app" under Azure AD B2C - App registrations (Preview) in Azure AD B2C. It's the app which stores the extension property in Azure AD B2C. Record its object ID.

Use the following call to register an extension in the app above. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#register-an-extension--).

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{your B2C tenant}/applications/<applicationObjectId>/extensionProperties
{
    "name": "customAttribute",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "Group"
    ]
}
```

Then you will get an extension for Group in the response: `extension_{client id of b2c-extensions-app}_customAttribute`.

Now create a group with the extension property.

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{your B2C tenant}/groups
{
  "displayName": "Example Group",
  "mailNickname": "ExampleGroup",
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "securityEnabled": true,
  "extension_{client id of b2c-extensions-app}_customAttribute": "customAttribute for group"
}
```